# \parbox vs. minipage: Differences in applicability

Tags: boxes, minipage

Lamport, *LaTeX: A document preparation system*, states on p. 104:

> There are two ways to make a parbox at a given point in the text: with the `\parbox` command and the `minipage` environment. They can be used to put one or more paragraphs of text inside a picture or in a table item.

`\parbox` and `minipage` share one mandatory argument (width of the parbox) and the optional argument (vertical alignment). (The second mandatory argument of `\parbox` *"is the text to be put in the parbox"* [p. 105].) Lamport recommends the use of minipages instead of parboxes in some cases (e.g. a parbox containing a `tabbing` or a list-making environment), but doesn't substantiate his advice (or at least I skipped that part). Finally, from Hendrik Vogt's comment to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/raggedleft-and-raggedright-simultaneously/6442#6442) answer, I gather that one reason to prefer minipages is that *"[y]ou don't have to wait that long for the matching closing brace"*.

I'm aware that the `\footnote` command doesn't work with `\parbox`; by contrast, it *"puts a footnote at the bottom of the parbox produced by the [`minipage`] environment"* (Lamport, p. 105). Are there other differences in applicability between `\parbox` and the `minipage` environment?

P.S.: Kopka and Daily, *A guide to LaTeX*, state on p. 89:

> The *text* in a `\parbox` may not contain any of the centering, list, or other environments described in Sections 4.2 through 4.5. These may, on the other hand, appear within a `minipage` environment.

However, I did some tests using `center`, `itemize` and `tabbing` environments within a `\parbox`, and LaTeX did not throw error messages. Are Kopka and Daly wrong, or did I miss something?

Comment: Perhaps I meant _syntactic_?

Comment: @Hendrik: Perhaps I should only quote statements I get the hang of? (But I *do* grasp the concept of matching braces, I swear!)

Comment: I'm rather sure you fully got what I meant. I'm just not so sure which word would have been adequate where I wrote "semantically" ...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The main reason I see to use `minipage` over `\parbox` is to allow verbatim (`\verb`, `verbatim`, etc.)  text inside the box (unless, of course, you also put the `minipage` inside a macro argument).

**EDIT** Here are other differences between `minipage` and `\parbox` (from the comments to Yiannis' answer and from looking at the source code of both these macros in [source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf)).

A first difference, as already mentioned by lockstep in his question, is in the footnote treatment: `minipage` handles them by putting them at the bottom of the box while footnotes are lost in a `\parbox` (to avoid this, you must resort to the `\footnotemark`/`footnotetext` trick):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{3cm}{text\footnote{parbox footnote}}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}text\footnote{minipage footnote}\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

A second difference is in that `minipage` resets the `\@listdepth` counter, meaning that, inside a `minipage`, you don't have to worry about the `list` nesting level when using them. Here's an example which illustrates the point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{list}{}{}\item\begin{list}{}{}\item\begin{list}{}{}\item\begin{list}{}{}\item
    \begin{list}{}{}\item\begin{list}{}{}
  \item %\parbox{5cm}{\begin{list}{}{}\item \end{list}}% error
  \item %\begin{minipage}{5cm}\begin{list}{}{}\item \end{list}\end{minipage}% no error
\end{list}\end{list}\end{list}\end{list}\end{list}\end{list}
\end{document}
```

A third difference is that `minipage` sets the boolean `\@minipagefalse` which in turn deactivates `\addvspace` if it's the first thing to occur inside a `minipage`. This means that `minipage` will have better spacing and allow better alignment compared to `\parbox` in some cases like the following (left is `minipage`, right is `\parbox`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Pros: \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\begin{itemize}\item first \item second%
    \end{itemize}\end{minipage}
Cons: \parbox[t]{3cm}{\begin{itemize}\item first \item second\end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One can (apparently, I've never tried it) use the [`footnote` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/footnote) to get sane behavior with footnotes in both `\parbox` and `minipage`.

Comment: @TH: the footnote package does the right thing (or did 15 years ago when i tried it), but it's pretty old now and one might expect it to interact badly with other sophisticated packages.

Comment: @lockstep: I know it's not a common practice, but I *did* put those braces around environments on purpose (clearer distinction between commands and environments). Oh, and there's still one left (the line beginning with **EDIT**).

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet I corrected the one left. If you feel strongly about the braces, please use the "rollback"  feature to revert to the former version of the post, and I will refrain from editing it again.

Comment: So is there any reason ever to use `\parbox` other than when you want to type slightly less?

Comment: @Christian: not really, no. An additional difference, though: the values of `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` are untouched by `\parbox` but changed to the `{minipage}` width.

Answer (score 16):

When your text you wish to enclose contains only a small piece of text then use `\parbox`. It should have nothing fancy inside such as any of the paragraph making environments. For larger pieces of text, such as those that do contain paragraph-making environments you should use a `minipage` environment.

There are also more subtle differences between the two such as the amount of space left on top etc. In general a `minipage` acts like a full page, whereas a `parbox` acts more like a fancy paragraph. Both of them offer very little semantic meaning - in my opinion. You can add semantic meaning by creating new environments with macro names that reflect their function in the document structure. For example you could define one of those boxes that one finds in manuals with a framed warning, a `warning box` using `parbox` and call it `warning`.

Comment: @Yannis: You're right that neither `\parbox` nor `minipage` offer semantic meaning. As for "`\parbox`[...] should have nothing fancy inside such as any of the paragraph making environments", I'd like to hear *why* this is so.

Comment: @lockstep It's not as if the fate of the earth depends on it, but if you do you will get all sorts of errors. If there is an answer to the *why* it can be found in `ltboxes.dtx` in the `source2e` (it beat me I don't really make heads or tails out of it!) but from what I can gather the `parbox` is just a box while the `minipage` is an environment based on `parbox`. To simplify my life, I mostly use `minipage`.

Comment: @Yannis: I'd like to see an example where `\parbox` results in an error but `minipage` doesn't. (That is, an example without using `verbatim` stuff.)

Comment: @Yannis: Thanks for pointing me to `source2e`.

Comment: @lockstep: as you can see by looking at `source2e`, `{minipage}` resets `\@listdepth` whereas `\parbox` does not. So if you nest six `\begin{list}{}{}\item...\end{list}` inside each other and then use another one in a `\parbox`, there will be a `too deeply nested` error which would not appear if you had used `{minipage}`.

Comment: @lockstep Most of the environments will work, but will possibly have small differences. But you correct in saying that they work in both `parbox` and `minipage` and I agree with you that Kopka and Daly and possibly Lamport did not state clearly the differences and imply that the commands will just be `broken`. `Quotation`, `quote`, `enumerate`, `itemize` all work as you mentioned with possibly the only difference is that mentioned by Philippe.

Answer (score 5):

If you make a new environment, you must enclose the body of the environment using `lrbox` first, then use the saved box in `\parbox`. But if you use minipage instead of `\parbox`, `lrbox` is no longer needed.

Comment: depending on what you're doing, that's only partially true. For example, if you want to put the content of an environment inside a macro (let's say `\fbox`), you need the `{lrbox}` whether you use `\parbox` or `{minipage}`.

Comment: @Philippe: You can't use `\parbox` macro to collect the content of an environment in any case. It is true, that you need to box the content first to use it in a macro later, but that is not the fault of `minipage`.

Answer (score 3):

**Simplification**
*([MaestroGlanz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101265/maestroglanz))*

The `minipage` resets the `textwidth` equal its `width`
while the `parbox` leaves the `textwidth` unchanged:

The following code renders a `parbox` and a `minipage`
with their `textwidth` displayed by the `\the` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth=400pt
\begin{document}
\parbox{100pt}{\the\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{100pt}\the\textwidth\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Here's the compiled output:

[image: ParboxMinipage]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example, where parbox behaves very different from minipage:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}% 

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\ns{%
    \hskip 0pt plus 1fill minus 1fill%
}%\ns

\newcommand{\notentext}[1]{%
    \linebreak[1]%
    \noindent%
    \makebox[\textwidth]{#1}%
}%

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
        \mbox{}\notentext{Text \ns Text \ns Text}%mbox{} prevents no-line-to-end-error
    \end{minipage} 
}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}%
        \mbox{}\notentext{Text \ns Text \ns Text}%mbox{} prevents no-line-to-end-error
        \notentext{Text \ns Text \ns Text}%
    \end{minipage}%
}



\fbox{
    \parbox{0.6\textwidth}{\mbox{}\notentext{Text \ns Text \ns Text}}
}
\fbox{
    \parbox{0.3\textwidth}{%
    \mbox{} \notentext{Text \ns Text \ns Text}%mbox{} prevents no-line-to-end-error
    \notentext{Text \ns Text \ns Text}
}%
}

\makebox{}


\end{document}
```

The hskip plus/minus 1fill behaves different. In minipage, it is limited to the minipage (`\textwidth` != original `\textwidth`), in parbox it relates to the whole textwidth (`\textwidth` = original `\textwidth`).

[image: Output]

Comment: Inside `minipage`, `\textwidth` refers to the width of the minipage; this is not true in `\parbox`, where `\textwidth` continues to refer to the overall width of the type block.

Comment: @egreg That was almost just out of where I developed the code. I simplified it now. If you are interested, why I did some strange stuff: Defining `\ns` inside `\notentext` is a good idea, because in that way it wont interfere with other definitions of `\ns` (It is only used in `\notentext`). The global assignment is also necessary, because I put the whole thing in extra `{ }`, which make them local. You probably read over them, which isnt your fault, since spaghetti code.

Comment: @egreg I changed it to less confusing text.