# How to put a long piece of text in a box?

Tags: boxes

I want to put a long piece of text in a box, for example

```
The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
jumps right over the lazy dog.
```

How can this be done? Any suggestion in brief.

Comment: A better answer to this question has been given at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36528/8666, where the `mdframed` package is suggested.

Answer (score 144):

You can use `\fbox{...}` to put a frame around a `\parbox{...}` containing your text. Here's an example document. Note the `\noindent` that prevents the box from being shifted to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog.
    }%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\linewidth` for two column layout

Comment: If I was to add this to an enumerate, how could I make sure that the box is shifted to the left margin of the page?

Comment: What do the % symbols do in this?  I know it's a comment symbol but it doesn't look like you're commenting anything.

Comment: The `%` are added to prevent the creation of unwanted characters, e.g. linebreaks messing with the spacing around the box.

Comment: Use `\linewidth - 2\fboxsep` for two column layout and the box around text to align with text.

Answer (score 81):

A `minipage` environment is a sufficient way to box or group something:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{15em}
  The quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
  dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy 
  dog. the quick brown fox jumps right over the lazy dog. the quick brown fox 
  jumps right over the lazy dog.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Minipage]

If you want to frame it, you can put a `\fbox` command around it. That is,

```
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{15em}
...
\end{minipage}}
```

[image: Minipage + fbox]

Answer (score 43):

The solutions with `\fbox` and `minipage` or `\parbox` all have the defect that the text will be an indivisible object which can't be split across pages. For a one shot application it might be the way to go. Otherwise there's the **mdframed** package that's highly customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
Test
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

You can find more information in the **mdframed** documentation:
https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf

Answer (score 30):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\medskip

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{%
    \minipage[t]{\dimexpr0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \lipsum[2]
    \endminipage}\hfill
    \fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{%
    \minipage[t]{\dimexpr0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
        \lipsum[3]
    \endminipage}

\medskip

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Notes:

- You can adjust the thickness  of border and padding of `\fcolorbox{<border-color>}{<background-color>}{<contents>}` by setting `\fboxrule=<value><unit>` and `\fboxsep=<value><unit>`, respectively. Put the setting before invoking `\fcolorbox{<border-color>}{<background-color>}{<contents>}`. For example: `\fboxrule=1pt` and `\fboxsep=5pt`.
- Use `t`, `c` and `b` options to align the base line of the most top row, the center row and the most bottom row with the surrounding baseline.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the best answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25926/120007, using `mdframed`.

But previously, improving upon other answers I've defined a new command which works in single column mode and two column mode:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[]{mdframed}


% draw a frame around given text
\newcommand{\framedtext}[1]{%
\par%
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{#1}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\section{This uses mdframed}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-
piscing vitae, felis.
\begin{mdframed}
A long sentence with multiple words and a sample equation $e^{i\pi}+1=0$.
\end{mdframed}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-
piscing vitae, felis.

\section{This uses the new command}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-
piscing vitae, felis.
\framedtext{A long sentence with multiple words and a sample equation $e^{i\pi}+1=0$.}

\lipsum[4-7]

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the latex above]

See also:

- [\parbox vs. minipage: Differences in applicability](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/parbox-vs-minipage-differences-in-applicability)
- [Error Overfull \hbox (6.79999pt too wide) in paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466298/error-overfull-hbox-6-79999pt-too-wide-in-paragraph)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to specify the dimensions of the box (width and height) that is supposed to contain the text, please check this question: [Fit text into given box by adjusting the fontsize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/fit-text-into-given-box-by-adjusting-the-fontsize)