# Line breaks in \fbox

Tags: boxes

I sometimes have bits of text I want to emphasize. My idea is to change the margin with `changepage`'s `adjustwidth` and then frame the text with `\fbox`. The problem is this prevents linebreaks. For now, the only solution I have is to put `\vbox` inside `\fbox` and split the text into `\hbox`es by copying the automatic line division and hyphenation carried out without `\fbox`. This also implies having to stretch some `\hbox`es, therefore calculating the opportune width for those. Is there a better way to do this? The idea is:

[image]

typeset by:

```
metodi numerici sui problemi di Cauchy, dà una definizione che è tutto fuorché matematica, nel senso che dà una definizione di questo tipo:
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
\dimen1=\linewidth
\advance\dimen1 by -0.3cm
\fbox{\itshape\vbox{\just[\dimen1]{Se un problema con una regione di stabilità finita in un intervallo di tem-} \just[\dimen1]{po per ogni condizione iniziale è forzato ad usare un passo di integrazione} \just[\dimen1]{troppo piccolo rispetto alla regolarità della soluzione il problema è stiff in} \hbox{quell'intervallo.}}}
\end{adjustwidth}
Tipicamente vado a scegliere i metodi con una regione di assoluta stabilità infinita, e tipicamente quelli che permettono con facilità di cambiare il passo di integrazione. Ovviamente
```

**Note:** `\just` is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\just}[2][\linewidth]{\hbox to #1{#2}}
```

**Edit:** I'm probably using all those `\hbox`es to avoid this:

[image]

Apart from the indent, which can be suppressed by `\noindent`, why does the text extend not only beyond the margin of `adjustwidth` but also beyond that of the text outside it? Is it because `\textwidth` is set back to normal and needs to be altered? Note that altering `\linewidth` changes nothing.

Comment: Why not a centered `minipage` or even better `tcolorbox`?

Comment: I'm afraid I basically know neither :). I haven't even ever heard of the latter.

Comment: The construction seems similar to a single-cell `tabular` where you could use a `p{<len>}`-column. Then the content will wrap all day long...

Comment: don't use `\vbox` in latex documents, it is a tex primitive so can be used in code with care but not taking top level document text like this, but even if you did you `\vbox` why the `\hbox` which just stops line breaking? why not just put the text into the `\vbox` and let tex break it into lines?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please see the edit.

Comment: `\vbox` just starts a new vertical list it doesn't reset parameters to be suitable for typesetting in that new context. `minipage` is `\vbox` but sets `\hsize` and `\parindent` and several other things, and works correctly with colour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you want

```
metodi numerici sui problemi di Cauchy, 
dà una definizione che è tutto fuorché matematica, 
nel senso che dà una definizione di questo tipo:
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}
\itshape
 Se un problema con una regione di stabilità 
 finita in un intervallo di tempo per ogni 
 condizione iniziale è forzato ad usare un passo
 di integrazione troppo piccolo rispetto alla regolarità 
della soluzione il problema è stiff in quell'intervallo.
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Yep, that also adds vertical space above and below. Perfect.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `minipage` rather than `\parbox`? I only ask because I tend to use the latter rather than the former and would like to know if I ought not do so.

Comment: @cfr minipage is essentially an environment form of parbox (they mostly use the same code internally) but like most environments it has the advantage that verb/verbatim can be used (but not here because of the fbox) minipage  resets a few more "page" oriented things and allows footnotes within the "minipage" which is either good or bad depending on which you want

Comment: Thanks. So `\parbox` is not bad when it works? I tend to use `\parbox` in these sorts of cases when it works and `minipage` when `\parbox` doesn't. I take it from your answer I'm not doing anything too awful.

Comment: @cfr as I say if you're not using footnotes or verb, there's not much difference (slightly different behaviour of white space at the top where minipage tries harder to be like a page and drop space) tabular p column is more or less same as parbox of course as well.

Comment: Similar question: [boxes - How to put a long piece of text in a box? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/how-to-put-a-long-piece-of-text-in-a-box)

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to David's answer, setting the quote inside a `tabular` using a fixed-width `p`-column. The optional parameter to `centerquote` is used to indicate the text block adjustment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{centerquote}[1][1cm]
 {\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1-#1}|}
  \hline}
 {\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{centerquote}
  \lipsum*[2]
\end{centerquote}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{centerquote}[2cm]
  \lipsum*[4]
\end{centerquote}

\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```