# Error Overfull \hbox (6.79999pt too wide) in paragraph

Tags: width

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage

\begin{document}

    \noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        {PGDM2018: Microeconomics}       \hspace{30mm}{November 2018-January 2019}
        \begin{center}
            Lecture 15: 7 Dec 2018
        \end{center}
        \\{Lecturer: Dr.Rakesh Nigam}
        \hspace{20mm}{Scribes: Vaibbhav Devender Kalra}
    }%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `Overfull \hbox (6.79999pt too wide) in paragraph` is a warning, not an error.  As for your MWE, I see an error because you are using `\\ ` immediately following `\end{center}`.  You can remove this error by removing `\\ `

Answer (score 3):

The `\parbox` is too wide, even at `\textwidth`, since the surrounding `\fbox` pads its contents on all sides by `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`. Remove this to avoid the overfull `\hbox` *warning*s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    PGDM2018: Microeconomics
    \hfill November 2018-January 2019
    \begin{center}
      Lecture 15: 7 Dec 2018
    \end{center}
    Lecturer: Dr.Rakesh Nigam
    \hfill Scribes: Vaibbhav Devender Kalra
  }%
}

\end{document}
```