# fbox of parbox of textwidth length is too wide

Tags: spacing, margins, parbox, fbox

I was implementing the code found in this Q/A [How to put a long piece of text in a box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/how-to-put-a-long-piece-of-text-in-a-box) to create a command for a paragraph text inside a framed box. However the box goes too far into the margin causing an `Overfull \hbox` warning. Running the code from the accepted answer gives the same problem. My expectation was that by providing  `\textwidth`as an argument would have the box be the proper width, but it does not (probably because of padding within the boxes?). How do I go about getting this box to be the proper width?

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\newcommand{\answer}[1]{
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{\linewidth}{%
            #1 \hfill
        }
    }%
}


\begin{document}

\answer{test}

\end{document}
```

I know the alternative of using `tcolorbox`, but I'm still interested in fixing this without using it.

Comment: An `\fbox`has the width of its contents plus 2 `\fboxsep` plus 2 `\fboxrule`. Try `\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}`.

Comment: In addition, don't forget `}%`.