# vertical spacing on enumitem

Tags: spacing, lists, boxes, minipage, enumitem

In the example below I want the enumerate list to essentially be ``inline'' with the word Example from the example environment. It works perfectly with text or enumerate* (inline list), but I cannot seam to figure out how to control some the remainder of the spacing created by the enumerate environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
    \theoremstyle{define}
      \newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
  \fbox{\parbox[t]{9cm}{
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),nosep]
      \item The duplicate ratio of $2a:3b$ is $4a^2:9b^2$.
      \item The subduplicate ratio of $49:25$ is $7:5$.
      \item The triplicate ratio of $2x:1$ is $8x^3:1$.
    \end{enumerate}
  }}
\end{example}
\begin{example}
  \fbox{Can you see the difference?}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to original posting

Have you tried using `minipage` instead of `\parbox`?

```
\begin{example}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}%
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),nosep]
      \item The duplicate ratio of $2a:3b$ is $4a^2:9b^2$.
      \item The subduplicate ratio of $49:25$ is $7:5$.
      \item The triplicate ratio of $2x:1$ is $8x^3:1$.
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{example}
```

Look at this answer to [\parbox vs. minipage: Differences in applicability](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6486/22413) to see an explanation of the differences between `\parbox` and `minipage`.  In particular, note the third difference listed in the answer.

## Issue with `hyperref`

A MWE for `hyperref` is realized as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\noindent
  Hello
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item The duplicate ratio of $2a:3b$ is $4a^2:9b^2$.
        \item The subduplicate ratio of $49:25$ is $7:5$.
        \item The triplicate ratio of $2x:1$ is $8x^3:1$.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Something seems to be happening with how `hyperref` is manipulating `\item` within an `enumerate` environment.  If you use `itemize` or create your own `list` environment, the spacing issue vanishes.  It also vanishes if you use `\item[]` as the first item in an `enumerate` environment (though I'm sure this is not what you want to do).

Comment: This is great! If I add \usepackage{hyperref} to the preamble it breaks it though. What is going on here?

Comment: @Raisdead There seems to be a deeper issue going on here.  I've posted a new question about how `hyperref` is interacting with `enumerate`d lists:  see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118937/22413)