# Hyperref inserting undesired space at start of enumerate environments

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, minipage

This question arises from my attempt to answer [vertical spacing on enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118925/22413).  Originally, I was able to answer the OP's question, but then the OP mentioned that the problem re-emerged if the `hyperref` package was used.

The following is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\noindent
  Hello
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item the first item
        \item the second item
        \item the third item
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

When expecting:

[image]

which is easily obtained from the MWE by commenting out the call to use `hyperref`.

After playing a bit with the contents `hyperref`, the problem seems to lie with how `hyperref` redefines how `\item` used in an `enumerate` environment.  In particular, the macro `\hyper@refstepcounter` seems to be at the root of the problem since by redefining it as

```
\def\hyper@refstepcounter#1{\relax}
```

eliminates the unwanted extra vertical space.

The definition of `\hyper@refstepcounter` is

```
\def\hyper@refstepcounter#1{%
  \edef\This@name{#1}%
  \ifx\This@name\name@of@eq
    \@ifundefined{theHequation}{%
      \make@stripped@name{\theequation}%
      \let\theHequation\newname
    }{}%
  \fi
  \HyCnt@ProvideTheHCounter{#1}%
  \hyper@makecurrent{#1}%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
%-->
      \hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend
    }%
  \fi
}
```

If you comment our the line following `%-->`, the extra vertical spacing disappears.

The raised link seems to be the problem, is this a bug in terms of how it's essentially counteracting how `minipage` eliminates the effects of `\addvspace`?  Or is there some trick that is a work around (other than commenting out this line)?

**EDIT**

One option for fixing this seems to be writing

```
\let\ifmeasuring@\iftrue
```

(or is this less drastic)

```
\measuring@true
```

after calling `hyperref` package.  But, I'm not really sure what the raised link is supposed to be achieving here.  Am I possibly throwing out too much by doing this?  Or might `amsmath` simply override this later---which seems unlikely because `\measuring@false` is only called from within a group.

Comment: You could wrap up the `enumerate` environment in a `NoHyper` environment.

Comment: Two needs fight with each other: the `hyperref` anchor has to be placed *above* the item number, so that a click on a hyperlink will show the item and not place the view below it. On the other hand, this introduces an element in the vertical list (the `minipage`) that sets a different reference point than expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two needs fight with each other: the `hyperref` anchor has to be placed above the item number, so that a click on a hyperlink will show the item and not place the view below it. On the other hand, this introduces an element in the vertical list (the `minipage`) that sets a different reference point than expected.

Here's a workaround for this particular case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\noindent
  Hello\rlap{\kern-2cm\vrule height 0pt depth 0.2pt width 11cm}
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item The duplicate ratio of $2a:3b$ is $4a^2:9b^2$.
        \item The subduplicate ratio of $49:25$ is $7:5$.
        \item The triplicate ratio of $2x:1$ is $8x^3:1$.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}}}

\end{document}
```

The `\rlap` is used to draw a rule showing the baseline.

[image]

If no hyperlink to the first item is needed, one can do with

```
\noindent
  Hello\rlap{\kern-2cm\vrule height 0pt depth 0.2pt width 11cm}
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{NoHyper}
        \item The duplicate ratio of $2a:3b$ is $4a^2:9b^2$.
        \end{NoHyper}
        \item The subduplicate ratio of $49:25$ is $7:5$.
        \item The triplicate ratio of $2x:1$ is $8x^3:1$.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}}
```

that producse the same result.

Comment: Is there a reason this *anchor* is not placed in a box whose height is `0pt`?

Comment: The reason for my previous comment is that this *anchor* is also disrupting the height used by `\fbox`.

Comment: @A.Ellett `\fbox` uses whatever is the reference point of its contents. It is raised because otherwise a click on a link pointing to the anchor would *hide* the text, not show it: PDF viewers go to the link placing it at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{9cm}\vspace{0pt}% define a line for vertical positioning
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item the first item
    [...]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect.