# Hyperref insert spurious space before list and minipage

Tags: spacing, hyperref, minipage, enumitem

Just including the `hyperref` package seems to be inserting spurious space *before* a `minipage` *and* *before* a list.  The MWE below produces the image on the right, but if the

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

line is commented out, we get the spacing on the left.

Note that additional space is inserted

- *before* the `minipage` and
- *before* the first list item.

I would like to eliminate *both* of these.

[image]
[image]

---

#### Update: 2019-05-08

Using

```
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\nointerlineskip\noindent
```

as per Heiko's answer, indeed remove the excess space *before* the `minipage` (second MWE), but does *not* remove the excess vertical space *before* the first list `\item`:

[image]

By commenting out the `\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}` in the second MWE you can see the desired spacing before the first `\item`.

### Note:

- Using `being{NoHyper}... \end{NoHyper}` is not really an option as I have links within the text. I don't need to be able to link back to the list `\item` though (in case that helps).

---

### Listfiles

```
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
showframe.sty    2011/02/24 v0.1i showframe (new impl., RN)
 eso-pic.sty    2015/07/21 v2.0g eso-pic (RN)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

### Code: Original

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[textwidth=4.5cm]{geometry}% For better images to compare

\usepackage{showframe}

%% Correct spacing if this is commented out
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}%
\noindent
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][3.0cm][t]{3.5cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First Item
            \item Second Item
            \item Third Item
            \item Fourth Item
        \end{enumerate}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}%
```

### Updated Code: Fixes spacing *before* `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[textwidth=4.5cm]{geometry}% For better images to compare

\usepackage{showframe}

%% Correct spacing if this is commented out
\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}%
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\nointerlineskip\noindent
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][3.0cm][t]{3.5cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First Item
            \item Second Item
            \item Third Item
            \item Fourth Item
        \end{enumerate}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: It works with a simple `\parbox{3.5cm}` however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That resolves the issue with the space _before_ the `parbox`, but still has additional space _before_ the list.

Comment: True, I thought you want to remove the space before the box only

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Good point. Have updated the question to make it explicit that _both_ additional spaces are not deisred.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Option `t` is important for the problem here, try `\parbox[t]{3.5cm}`.

Comment: Related Questions: [Hyperref inserting undesired space at start of enumerate environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118937/4301), [Text is shifted when using `hyperref` package or when creating a new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531812/4301).

Answer (score 10):

Package `hyperref` has to insert anchors, otherwise inner-document links would not work. Thus, the topmost element of the `enumerate` environment is the anchor for the first `\item`. As side effect, the `minipage` with option `t` is no longer aligned at the base line of the topmost line, but the topmost element, the anchor.
This causes the full `\topskip` to be shown at the start of the page.

Workaround:

```
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\nointerlineskip
\noindent
\fbox{...}
```

If the `hyperref` features are not needed inside the `\fbox`, then the anchors can be disabled by:

```
\begin{NoHyper}
...
\end{NoHyper}
```

The spacing and anchors can be seen by `\showlists`, e.g.:

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \fbox{...}

  \showlists
\end{document}
```

Comment: That resolves the spacing _before_ the `minipage`, but still insertes additional space _before_ the first list items.

Comment: I do not need hyperref to refer to the list items, but _do_ need to be able to have hyperref linked text/math in the body.

Comment: @PeterGrill Then you can use environment `NoHyper` for the parts, where the anchors of `hyperref` messes up the spacing and it is not needed.

Comment: I think I would need the apply `NoHyper` around the `\item` but  then the lsit complains about missing `\item`.   The `\vspace` hack is fine, but need an equivalent hack for the the `enumitem` list so that the first item is moved above the correct amount, but I don't know what that amount is. Also, I thought that perhaps setting `topsep` to a negative amount would move the first item up but doesn't seem to.

Comment: @PeterGrill a) Put the whole list in `NoHyper`. b) The amount can be seen/calculated from the output of `\showlists`.

Comment: If I put the whole list in `NoHyper`, the links in the body are disabled. I need the text in the body to have links such as `\href{run:foo.pdf}{My PDF}`, just don't need to be able to link back to the list. Thus, don't think the `NoHyper` is an option for me. As I don't know how to read the output of `showlists`, I will post a separate question for that.

Answer (score 10):

**[updated 2023-10]**

If you know that you don't need to link to the first item you can suppress the whatsit (and so the space) like this in a current LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[textwidth=4.5cm]{geometry}% For better images to compare

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[colorlinks,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\newcommand\nohyperitem{\LinkTargetOff \item \LinkTargetOn}

\begin{document}%
\noindent
xx\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][3.0cm][t]{3.5cm}
        \begin{enumerate}
         \nohyperitem First Item
            \item Second Item
            \item Third Item
            \item Fourth Item
        \end{enumerate}%
    \end{minipage}%
}%

\end{document}%
```

[image]

Comment: Starting with `hyperref` v7.01a (2023-06-25), `amsmath` is required to make the trick work. This is because `hyperref` changed the way it patches `amsmath`. Before, in `\refstepcounter` the whatsit (more specifically an anchor) is not inserted if `\ifmeasuring@` is true, no matter `amsmath` is loaded or not. After, the whatsit will still be inserted if `\ifmeasuring@` is true _but_ `amsmath` is not loaded. What's unchanged is `\ifmeasuring@` is always available.

Comment: See related hyperref commits [19abb836](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/commit/19abb836ebfd002e0491303e0558907ea23065a3) and [8c7758a4](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/commit/8c7758a4bc6e5631d0c4ebe62ba6eef591b40d8c).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ right. I have updated the answer to avoid internals.