# ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode

Tags: graphics, errors, minipage

I am using an image within `minipage` and getting error message.

```
  ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

Below is minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm,right=1cm, left=1cm, headsep=26pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}           
\begin{minipage}[t]{.98\linewidth}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
 ABC
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\linewidth}
  \hspace{2cm}
\end{minipage}

 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} \textbf{Some text} \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\linewidth} \begin{figure}[h!]   \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{risk2.png} \end{figure} \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}             % Error is due to using figure in minipage

\end{minipage}
\end{document}             % End of document.
```

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You cannot use a `figure` within a `minipage`. Remove the surrounding `minipage`.

Comment: Remove `\begin{figure}[h!]` and `\end{figure}`. Please include only `\includegraphics[...]{...}`.

Comment: As Jagath AR says, there is no need to put `\includegraphics` in a `figure` environment. TeX sees `\includegraphics[...]{...}` just like a big letter.

Comment: If i remve this i cannot use caption and also text which is adjacent in next minipage seems to be hanging down.

Comment: Load `caption` (`\usepackage{caption}`) and use `\captionof{figure}{your caption}` to get caption outside `figure` environment. `\captionof` command is also provided by `capt-of` package

Comment: But still text in the adjacent mini-page is hanging.

Comment: I have just uploaded the output after removing \begin{figure}[h!] and \end{figure} but "Some text" and "ABC" in adjacent minipages are hanging down it should be in the same line (Top aligned). How can i fix this?

Comment: Only a general remark: You should try to substitute some of those `minipages` with a `parbox` command. It is more robust and hence may make life a little easier. Minipages are good if you want to use specific properties like `mpfootnotes`

Comment: I've just had the similar problem however I was not using `minipage` but `\begin{figure}` environment and the ` ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` error was due to a missing `\end{figure}`. You should look through your document and see if something like `\end{minipage}` is not missing.

Answer (score 67):

Firstly to summarise the comments: `figure` environments may not appear in `minipage`s.  `figure` is a floating environment, but you want to place your graphics in a particular place.  In principle, all you need is the `\includegraphics`, but as you notice, you do not get the vertical space you expect, so there may be other issues.

Let me run through your set-up to discuss several points.

Each `minipage` produces a box of typeset material, and these are placed essentially like individual characters you enter.  In particular, blank lines between `minipage`s will start new paragraphs and thus not stay on the same line.  So many of the blank lines in your sample code need to be removed.

Next given that, many of the other constructs you use do not need to be encapsulated in a `minipage`.  This applies in particular to the `\hspace` command.  You can just write

`\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}\hspace{...}\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}`

as you would write

```
a\hspace{...}b
```

to get horizontal spacing between objects.

Similarly, an image can be included directly; the `\includegraphics` command produces another box of typeset material that is again placed much like a character.  You can use `\raisebox` to adjust its vertical placing if necessary.

On the other hand, if you are using `figure` because you wanted to have a caption and figure number available, then using a `minipage` to include this and the caption would be appropriate.  You can then use the `caption` package, which as `\captionof` command:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
   \vspace{-2ex}
   \includegraphics{...}
   \captionof{figure}{Caption}
\end{minipage}
```

Note the use of a `\vspace` before the graphics; without it the first line of the `minipage` is very high, but the `[t]` option aligns on the baseline of the first line of the `minipage` so the image sticks up.  `-2ex` is essentially the height of a capital letter, and will place the image so its top edge aligns with those.  See [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11630/15925) for further discussion of such alignment of images in `minipage`s.

Here is a modified version of your example putting these things together (irrelevant packages have been stripped out):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm,right=1cm, left=1cm, headsep=26pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.98\linewidth}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1em}
    Some text over several lines.  
    Some text over several lines.  

    Some text over several lines in a new paragraph.
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{4em plus 1fill}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1em}
    Some text over several lines.  
    Some text over several lines.  

    Some text over several lines in a new paragraph.
  \end{minipage}
  \quad
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
    \vspace{-2ex}
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I have used `\quad` to space off the image `minipage` from the that for text to the left.  This is equivalent to `\hspace{1em}`.  For the space between the first two blocks, I used `\hspace{4em plus 1fill}`, this is a minimum of four quads but stretches to fill out the available room.  The effect here is that your first minipage is flushleft, and the last pair is pushed flushright.

In the `minipages`, I set the paragraph indents; they are zero by default.

Note that `minipage` is quite a complex construct.  It is appropriate if the material is long and includes several paragraphs.  If it is just a single paragraph then `\parbox` is a better choice.  See [\parbox vs. minipage: Differences in applicability](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6472/15925) for a discussion.

Comment: good answer. but `\show\quad` says `\hskip 1em\relax`, not 2em. `\qquad` is 2em wide.

Comment: @jakun Thanks! - now fixed

Comment: Thank you @AndrewSwann! I was trying to put a row of images, and a caption under them in the `\maketitle` section of a paper. `\titlepic` solves the placement part of that but it (for the same reason as `minipage`?) does not allow using a `figure` inside the brackets of `\titlepic{}` . Your answer is super helpful!

Answer (score 24):

Add `\usepackage{float}` and use the option `[H]` in the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} %figure inside minipage
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth} 
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{\label{fig:label} Figure title}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{filename}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just adding `[H]` worked for me whilst using `minted`.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian It is good practice to be explicit about your dependencies and load the packages you use. If `minted` stopped depending on `float`, your document would stop compiling and you may have no idea why.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me. I had the same issue with the `algorithm` environment and this solved it. :)

Answer (score 9):

The following is obviously not the source of your problem, but since it causes the same error, and this page is the first google hit for that error, I feel it might be useful for future readers to record it here anyway, if that's ok. So:

the

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

can also be caused by forgetting to type an `\end{table}` a couple of lines higher.

(Normally this would of course be detected by a `\begin{table} on line xxx followed by \end{document}` error, but in my case the large number of outer par mode errors caused an emergency stop before getting there.)

Comment: In my case, an `\end{figure}` was swallowed by an incomplete command that expected an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\usepackage{float`} and put the `minipage` (with grphics) inside figure.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How does this solve the answer? A little more code and a full example would be of more use