# How to put 2 cols in landscape oriented page?, 1col for 1figure, other for comments?

Tags: graphics, positioning, landscape

How can I obtain any similar to the image?
[image]

I was trying with similar things to

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
This is the 1st page of \jobname, with ONLY 1 col.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{example-image-a.eps}
  \caption{forma02}\label{forma02}
\end{figure}

And now, in the rigth column, I want to explain the letter A.\\

A is the first letter of the alphabet.
\begin{itemize}
  \item because YES
  \item because B is the 2nd
  \item and finally, because C is the 3rd.
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
The source document \jobname is OVER with this 1 col page.

\end{document}
```

---------------------  OR   ----------------------------

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
The source document is\jobname.

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}
  %\centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.eps}
  \caption{forma02}\label{forma02}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
Here are comments about the figure in this page
\begin{itemize}
  \item This is the first
  \item 2nd
  \item and the last
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` inside a `minipage`. See e.g., [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124346/latex-error-not-in-outer-par-mode). I added the `caption` package and removed the `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{incgraph,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
The source document is \jobname.

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{forma02}\label{forma02}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
Here are comments about the figure in this page
\begin{itemize}
  \item This is the first
  \item 2nd
  \item and the last
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```