# subfig vs exercise: LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode

Tags: graphics, subfloats, exercises

I'm able to use the `subfig` package in my documents, but not within an `exercise` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newcommand{\onefigure}[2]{%
\includegraphics[#1]{../../figures/ece1229/#2}%
}

\newcommand{\fourfigures}[5]{%
\begin{figure}%
\centering%
\subfloat[][]{\onefigure{scale=#1}{#2}}%
\qquad%
\subfloat[][]{\onefigure{scale=#1}{#3}}%
\qquad%
\subfloat[][]{\onefigure{scale=#1}{#4}}%
\qquad%
\subfloat[][]{\onefigure{scale=#1}{#5}}%
\end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
%\onefigure{scale=0.2}{blah1}
\fourfigures{0.2}{blah1}{blah2}{blah3}{blah4}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

When the subfloat is embedded in an exercise, I get a "Not in outer par mode" error, similar to that of the question [! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124346/latex-error-not-in-outer-par-mode).  For that question, the error was because a float is not allowed in a minipage.

I'm assuming that there is a similar restriction for floats in exercise environments.  Given this restriction, is there a way to make arrange multiple images in groups as with subfig but in some way that is still compatible with exercise?

Comment: Why do you want it in an `exercise` environment?

Comment: Because the are plots related to solving a problem that I've got in an exercise environment.  I actually want the plots in an answer environment of the same package, but I'm sure the idea is the same.

Comment: But you don't mind that they'll float away?

Comment: I used the [demo] mode for graphicsx in my mwe, and don't actually have a filename called blah in that directory.

Comment: I'd prefer they be near the answer, but if they aren't I don't mind so long as I can caption them, and refer to the caption in a reference.

Comment: Sorry. Missed the `demo`.

Comment: `subfig` is irrelevant, as is the use of KOMA Script. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{Exercise}
 \begin{figure}
 \onefigure{scale=0.2}{tiger}
  \end{figure}
  \end{Exercise}
\end{document}
` reproduces the error.

Comment: You can use `caption` to create captions outside floats. So you could just put the images in minipages and use `\captionof...` to caption them.

Comment: just remove the `figure` and use four `\includegraphics` commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This avoids the use of floats inside the `Exercise` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine,lipsum}

\newcommand\fourfigures[5]{%
\par\medskip{\centering%
\stackunder[6pt]{
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}}{(a)}
\qquad%
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#3}}{(b)}
}{
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#4}}{(c)}
\qquad%
\stackunder{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#5}}{(d)}
}\par}
}

\begin{document}
Pre-exeercise \lipsum[13]
\begin{Exercise}
In Exercise \lipsum[13]
\fourfigures{0.3}{blah1}{blah2}{blah3}{blah4}
\captionof{figure}{This is my figure caption}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}
Next exercise \lipsum[13]
\fourfigures{0.2}{blah1}{blah2}{blah3}{blah4}
\captionof{figure}{This is my figure caption}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer was provided in the comments (removing the figure and using the `includegraphics` directly), but some additional work is required to recover features available in the figure environment.  In particular, manual adjustment of the spacing is required, and captions have to be done differently.

On the spacing, by default the spacing doesn't appear to be chosen intelligently with `includegraphics`, and part of my plots can end up off the edge of the page:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals0DegreesFig1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals90DegreesFig2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals180DegreesFig3}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals270DegreesFig4}
```

[image: four figures]

With the spacing adjusted manually, and using the `captions` package, I can obtain something close to a `figure`+`subfloat` look:

```
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals0DegreesFig1}
\qquad
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals90DegreesFig2}
\par\vspace{5mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals180DegreesFig3}
\qquad
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{../../figures/ece1229/ps4p1PlotAdEquals270DegreesFig4}
\caption{Plots of ....}
\label{fig:fourangles}
\end{center}
```

[image: four figures 2]

Unfortunately, I lose the `subfig` (a), (b), (c), (d) markers, but this is at least close.

Comment: With the `stackengine` package, you can `\stackunder[5pt]{\includegraphics{...}}{(a)}`, etc. to recover the subfigure numbers.  However, that will still not allow subfigures to be labeled separately.  Also, if you are not in a `figure` environment, you will have to use `\captionof{figure}{}` instead of `\caption`.

Comment: You may be able to use `\captionof` from the `caption` package together with the `subcaption` package instead of `subfig` in order to get the numbering (a), (b), ... again.

Comment: If I use \captionof{figure}{(a)} or \subcaption{}, something forces a \par between the figures.  Any idea how to suppress that?