# How to rotate a table in "tabularray" environment with "\begin{turn}{180}" in LaTeX?

Tags: rotating, tabularray

I want to rotate a table of `tabularray` environment by `rotating` package in LaTeX.
When I tested, I found that there is an error about `tabularray`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{rotating} % <-- HERE

\begin{document}
\begin{turn}{180}
blabla dummy text
\begin{table}
        \begin{talltblr}[
            caption={1},
            label={tab:1}
            ]{
                colsep=0.3pt
            }
            Hello
        \end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{turn}
\end{document}
```

And the error is:
[image]

Is there a way to combine rotation with `tabularray`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `table` environment.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{rotating} % <-- HERE

\begin{document}
\begin{turn}{180}
blabla dummy text
        \begin{talltblr}[
            caption={1},
            label={tab:1}
            ]{
                colsep=0.3pt
            }
            Hello
        \end{talltblr}
\end{turn}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: looking up what the error message means you can easily come across [! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124346/latex-error-not-in-outer-par-mode) ...

then it's written in e.g. LaTeX unofficial reference manual that `table` is a floating environment. So you can't use `table` inside `turn`.

Alternatively, you can turn the table itself while keeping it floating by putting the `turn` environment inside the `table` environment.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{rotating} % <-- HERE

\begin{document}
blabla dummy text

\begin{table}
\begin{turn}{180}
        \begin{talltblr}[
            caption={1},
            label={tab:1}
            ]{
                colsep=0.3pt
            }
            Hello Hello Hello Hello
        \end{talltblr}
\end{turn}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: alternative 1 output]

Another alternative is to put both the text and the table inside the floating environment.

[image: alternative 2 output]

Comment: I find that there is a difference between having `table` and not having `table` in this case. What is the reason?

Comment: @Y.zeng Read up on "float environment" in LaTeX.

Comment: Okay. Let me try it.

Comment: Because `table` is really a shortcut to `FloatingBoxThatWillBeCaptionedAsATable` (similar for `figure`....)....  Jokes apart, confusing `table` as a something that create a table and `figure` as something that create a picture is quite common.

Comment: (for OP, if it's the case) Well there are e.g. captionof package to caption without float etc. e.g. [cross referencing - Label and caption without float - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float)