# Table Spanning the Textwidth

Tags: tables, indentation, margins

I am trying to create a very simple, one row table that spans the linewidth. When I use the following command:

`\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}

  Entry 1 & Entry 2

\end{tabular*}`

the first entry is slightly indented and the second entry entends past the linewidth. How do I make it so that the first entry is aligned with the left margin and the second entry is aligned with the right margin?

Comment: Why not just use `\noindent Entry 1 \hfill Entry 2`?

Comment: That is much simpler. I just didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Werner Indeed. Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/raggedleft-and-raggedright-simultaneously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\noindent` before `\begin{tabular*}` if you use the `tabular*` environment outside a `table` float.

EDIT: As Werner points out, you may also remove the `\tabcolsep` before the first and after the last column (using `@{}`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
Entry 1 & Entry 2
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]