# Indented table spanning the textwidth

Tags: tables

I want the table to be indented, but I don't want the second column to extend past the right margin.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
Entry 11 & Entry 12 \\
Entry 21 & Entry 22 
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

My example is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51571/table-spanning-the-textwidth).

Comment: Then you have to subtract `\parindent` from `\linewidth`

Comment: `\begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent}`.