# How will I align two words right and left in same line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Raggedleft and raggedright simultaneously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6440/raggedleft-and-raggedright-simultaneously)

I need to make a certificate page.
In it, I need the "head of the department" to be aligned right and "Guide" to be aligned left on the same line.
Please help me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{Guide\hfill head of the department}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless I misunderstood something, are you looking for [fancyhdr](ftp://www.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)?

Comment: how to install that package?

Comment: @Vidhya I think this should be included in most modern distributions.