# How can I force to print exactly at the end of the line?

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to force a linebreak, but at the same time I would like to force LaTeX to print at the and of the line, so I would like no space at the and of the line!

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The source is the question, for example something like this: text text text \newpage % but I want to force the following appearance:

Comment: instead of: text text text ... ... ... |

Comment: I would like: text ... text ... text |

Comment: where ... is some space, and | is the end of the line

Comment: Please add this explanations from your comments to your question above and delete the comments afterwards

Comment: Did you try `\linebreak`?

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [`\raggedleft` and `\raggedright` simultaneously](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6440/5764); [How to make text aligned left/center/right in the same line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55472/5764)

Comment: I have (I hope) a better answer, then expected by OP, hence voting for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\hfill`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}% to s the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
some text\hfill other text\hfill text\\
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]